# run a function when a user clicks on any list element

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is probably a very common question, but I was unable to find an answer myself;

All my list elements call the function setQuery like this

```
onClick="admin_stats.setQuery(this);"
```

rather than [hardcode] add this to every list element, is there a  way to simply have it run when a list element is clicked?

I'm not very familiar with jQuery Live or binding/unbinding, but I think they would play a role here?

Before I reinvent a rather square-looking wheel I thought I might ask =)

---

edit: my list elements look like

```
<ul>
    <li id="usersPerMonth" onClick="admin_stats.setQuery(this);">Users per Month</li>
    <li id="statsByUser" onClick="admin_stats.setQuery(this);">Stats by User</li>
</ul>
```

the this.attr("id") is then used to look up what the actually SQL text looks like, from a json-style variable:

```
queries : {
    usersPerMonth : " ... some sql ...",
    statsByUser   : " ... some sql ...",
    ...
}
```

so that's why I have the divs named that way (and I'm open to design suggestions)

Comment: Can you provide some sample html for your list elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $('#myList').delegate('li', 'click', function() {
        admin_stats.setQuery( this );
    });
});
```

This assumes your `<ul>` element has the ID `myList`. It will handle clicks inside of it on any `<li>` elements, calling your function, and passing `this` as the argument.

The  [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) code is wrapped in `$(function() {});` so that it doesn't run until the DOM is ready. This is a shortcut for jQuery's [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function.

Comment: @karim79: You've got it backwards. `.delegate()` is the answer, `.live()` is the alternative. ;o)

Comment: Do you know of any good tutorials (other than http://api.jquery.com/delegate/ (documentation)) that explain the differences between .live() and .delegate()?

Comment: @sova: They are effectively the same, except that `.delegate()` allows you to concentrate on a particular section of the page, while `.live()` looks at the entire document. They are both "event delegation" functions. That means that you place a handler on a container that processes events that occur inside of it. With your example, the handler is only concerned about clicks inside the `<ul>`. When a click occurs inside, it tests the element clicked agains the `'li'` selector. Had you used `.live()`, *every* click on the page, no matter where, would have to be tested using the `'li'` selector.

Comment: ...if you want to know more, google "javascript event delegation", and you'll get some generic (non-jQuery) examples of how it works. I really dislike `.live()`, because often people don't know that it is using event delegation. The `.delegate()` method rather makes you think in terms of the sub-section of the page (like your list) where the delegation is occurring.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - use jQuery like this:

```
$('li').live("click", function(event){
    admin_stats.setQuery(event.target);
});
```

This is assuming you want to set it to every `li` element.  You can find the documentation for `live` here: http://api.jquery.com/live/

What live does makes sure that all elements passed to it will always have the click handler in the function specified.

Comment: `admin_stats.setQuery(this);` ? +1 anyways.

Comment: you probably meant `.live('click', function() {})`

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is probably your best bet. Are you adding new elements on the fly, or will the elements be there when the attach is ready to go? If they're "satic" in the sense that once the page is loaded that's it, you could use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('li').bind('click',function(e){ // may need to change the selector to be more specific
    admin_stats.setQuery(this);
  });
});
```

Comment: the list is static for now, but I would like to add in-browser functionality to have users add more elements to it eventually.

Comment: if you are adding elements dynamically, you can put your li in a div and search for all <ki> to bind the function or give uniqe name to <ul> and search for all <li>. If you need i can give you the code, other than mentioned above.

Comment: @tsegay: the accepted answer by @patrickdw (using the delegate) is a great solution to @sova's problem.

Answer (score 1):

that needs to fire onClick... so:

```
 $('li').click(function(){
     admin_stats.setQuery($(this));
 });
```

Comment: I would suggest to add a class name to your li elements to avoid other li fire the admin_stats function.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you select elements using CSS-style selectors (can use this if more elements will not be added; this uses [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/)):

```
$(function() {
    $('#liContainer li').click(function() {
        admin_stats.setQuery(this);
    });
});
```

We put the whole thing inside `$(function() { ... });` because the page needs to be ready before binding the event handler. Alternatively, you could do it like this if more elements are added. This uses [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/):

```
$(function() {
    $('#liContainer').delegate('li', 'click', function() {
        admin_stats.setQuery(this);
    });
});
```